# Horizontal scroll event on jQM application

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developping a mobile application with jQM and I have simply imported it in an android web view. I have a horizontal scroll, which does not work properly locally under chrome, but is okay on the mobile device. I want to put some arrows, which should navigate the user if it's available to scroll left/right, but I can't even catch the scroll event. Here is my  [code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3y38A/1/) .

The critical code imo is

```
.swipe-container {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 102px;
margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}
```

because when I remove it, it becomes scrollable under the browser and I'm able to catch the event, but it does not look and behave the way I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure it's what you want, but I think the overflow-x: scroll should be given to the container: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/3y38A/2/

Comment: This is what I want actually, but now it works on the fiddle example, but does no on mine. I post a screenshot with the computed style and the way it looks on the project: http://postimg.org/image/52me9sxwb/full/

Comment: you want those bottom scrollbars to be one long scrollbar? can you put your site online somewhere and give us the link?

Comment: No, I want the div with the link blocks to be scrollable, just like in the fiddle example you have posted. The thing I want is to catch the scroll event, but right now I can't.
Atm I have some problem with the website, so I can't upload it, it does not work properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/3y38A/4/ it alerts the scroll..

Comment: Yeah, it works fine on jsfiddle, but does not for my project, I'm wondering why, considering the fact, that the css for both are the same...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37459/discussion-between-jonas-grumann-and-ivaylo-toskov)

Comment: I can't send any messages on chat... Еrror:
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'div' of object [object Object] is not a function

You can contact me on skype : ivcho9999